# RegEx to find numbers in a string using PowerShell

Tags: regex, string, powershell

Imagine having 500 string like this with different dates:

```
The certificate has expired on 02/05/2014 15:43:01 UTC.
```

Given that this is a String and I'am using powershell. I need to treat the date (02/05/2014) as an object, so I can use operatators (-lt -gt).

Is the only way doing this is using RegEx, and in this case - can anyone help me finding the first 6 numbers (which change every time) using regEx.

Comment: (1) are you sure you only need to compare the date part? What about two timestamps that only differ in time (not date), which one should then be treated as greater/less (since you menated `-lt`/`-gt`)? (2) Why only the "first six numbers"? Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: @Christian.K if this is really about certificate expiration, the time part is probably negligible, as we're talking years here. But true, it would be "more accurate". Make sure to compare in UTC!

Answer (score 2):

```
>$regexStr = "(?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})"
>$testStr = "The certificate has expired on 02/05/2014 15:43:01 UTC."
>$testStr -match $regexStr
# $Matches will contain the regex group called "date"
>$Matches.date
02/05/2014
>$date = Get-Date ($Matches.date)
>$date
Wednesday, February 5, 2014 12:00:00 AM
```

If you need to parse the date string with another format you can do:

```
 >$dateObj = [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches.date,”dd/MM/yyyy”,$null)
 >$dateObj.GetType()

  IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
  -------- -------- ----                                     --------
  True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

Hope that helps